# traceroute and ping behaviour through cisco router

Tags: ping, traceroute

Trying to do a traceroute to a particular destination, the result seems that the destination is unreachable. But when i ping the destination, the destination is replying well. could anyone help to interpret the below results :

TRACEROUTE :

```
R1#traceroute 
Protocol [ip]: 
Target IP address: 10.10.7.4
Source address: 10.10.1.2
Numeric display [n]: 
Timeout in seconds [3]: 
Probe count [3]: 
Minimum Time to Live [1]: 
Maximum Time to Live [30]: 
Port Number [33434]: 
Loose, Strict, Record, Timestamp, Verbose[none]: 
Type escape sequence to abort.
Tracing the route to 10.10.7.4

  1 10.10.1.254 0 msec 0 msec 4 msec
  2 10.100.10.117 8 msec 9 msec 10 msec
  3 10.100.16.133 9 msec 12 msec 15 msec
  4  *  *  *
  5  *  *  * 
  6  *  *  * 
  7  *  *  * 
  8  *  *  * 
  9  *  *  * 
 10  *  *  * 
 11  *  *  * 
 12  *  *  * 
 13  *  *  * 
 14  *  *  * 
 15  *  *  * 
 16  *  *  * 
 17  *  *  * 
 18  *  *  * 
 19  *  *  * 
 20  *  *  * 
 21  *  *  * 
 22  *  *  * 
 23  *  *  * 
 24  *  *  * 
 25  *  *  * 
 26  *  *  * 
 27  *  *  * 
 28  *  *  * 
 29  *  *  * 
 30  *  *  *
```

PING :

```
R1#ping 10.10.7.4 sou 10.10.1.2

Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.10.7.4, timeout is 2 seconds:
Packet sent with a source address of 10.10.1.2
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 20/20/24 ms
```

Comment: Apparently on a router with ID `10.100.16.133` (or on next behind him towards destination) UDP is blocked (Cisco traceroute uses UDP), but ICMP echo allowed.

Comment: @AndreyProkhorov You should make this an answer to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently on a router with ID `10.100.16.133` (or on next behind him towards destination) UDP is blocked (Cisco traceroute uses UDP), but ICMP echo allowed.

Comment: Or the host is not responding with the required "port unreachable" message.